# Responsive disign is not working with W3 Total Cache

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I'm using [Swift theme](http://swiftthemes.com/) and its a responsive theme. But my problem is whenever I activate W3Total Cache the theme size is not changing according to browser size. What may be the problem? Can anyone help me to rectify this issue.
My Blog [Digital Advices](http://www.digitaladvices.com/)
Regards,
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify how you've set up your W3C? If I had to guess, I'd say it has something to do with the minification and combining options. I'd suggest you disable those completely and check if it works.